# Why do styles from one CSS file affect another page's element in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have pages that I put in separate folders. Each page has its own CSS file. I have some classes with the same name in different pages. For example, pages A and B both have a `container` class. So, the question is, why does one of them apply the style that I wrote in a different file and folder even though I set different values for `container`?
The folder structure:

```
pages/
├─ pageB/
│  ├─ PageB.jsx
│  ├─ style.css
├─ pageA/
│  ├─ PageA.jsx
│  ├─ style.css
```

The `container` in `PageB.jsx` is applying the `style.css` from the pageA folder or vice versa.

Can't I use the same className but apply different styles that I've set in each `style.css` file? How can I make them apply the style from their own `style.css`?

Comment: Maybe consider using modules Like this -> https://medium.com/@ralph1786/using-css-modules-in-react-app-c2079eadbb87 Otherwise you can also use a css reset to try to reset those classes from overflowing... I don't know of there's a better solution. In general I recommend using more specific class names, and never overloading them (i.e. naming in more than 1 file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CSS Modules to encapsulate the styles for each component.

Here is the official documentation:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Basically you need to rename your files to `PageA.module.css`, `PageB.module.css` (or any other name, just make sure that it ends with `.module.css`) and then import it in a component that you want to use:

CSS file:

```
// PageA.module.css
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Component file:

```
// PageA.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './PageA.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    // reference as a js object
    return <button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>;
  }
}
```

That way React will generate unique names for the CSS classes in each module even if multiple CSS files have a class with the same name.

In the rendered HTML you will have something like this:

```
// PageA component:
<button class="PageA_error_abc">Error Button</button>

// PageB component:
<button class="PageB_error_xyz">Error Button</button>
```